# $routeChangeStart called twice when login page loads

Tags: angularjs

In my angular app, I have redirected the user to the '/home' route using the $routeProvide.otherwise function. But if the user is not logged in, then I am redirecting to login page using $routeChangeStart -

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
  console.log('$routeChangeStart');
  $rootScope.layout.loading = true;

  if ($rootScope.loggedIn === false) {

    if (next.templateUrl === "login/login.html") {
      // in order to skip this behavior when already navigating to the login page,
      // we have to explicitly check the next templateUrl
    } else {
      console.log('DENY: redirecting to login');
      //event.preventDefault();
      $location.path('/login');
    }
  } else {
    console.log('ALLOW');
  }

});
```

I've noticed in the console that $routeChangeStart is being called twice. Can't figure out why!

[Here is the working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WN38qe693NCzrqfZsBha?p=preview)

Comment: the first time is called when you're open the page and trying to go to "home". the second time is when you're redirecting to the login page.

Comment: Any solution to prevent the double call? In my actual app, the redirection to login page is actually taking place twice due to this.

Comment: add the $rootScope.$on event in your home controller (instead in .run()) and deregister the event when your redirecting to your login page.

Answer (score -3):

try

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current)
{

}
```